# Error publishing spfx package to AppSource

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, app-store

I'm facing an issue in publishing an app to the App Source. I have created a Marketplace Offer on Office Store, Offer Name is SharePoint Solution. Now in the third step of publishing an app, Packages I'm not seeing that it allows me to upload ab **sppkg** file. Still, I tried at that time I got the following error:

```
Package acceptance validation error: XML Schema Validation Error Error found during XML Schema validation. Error code: The element 'Properties' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest' has invalid child element 'AppIconPath' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest'. List of possible elements expected: 'SupportPage, SupportedLanguages, UninstallingEventEndpoint, StartPage, InstalledEventEndpoint, UpgradedEventEndpoint, SettingsPage, WebTemplate' in namespace.

Package acceptance validation error: XML Schema Violation Your manifest does not adhere to the current set of XML schema definitions for Office Add-in manifests.
```

Can you tell me where I'm missing something? Do we need to generate a package differently? Please help me.

I have seen that this issue was already resolved in 2020.I have seen that [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6070)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue yesterday - AppIconPath element that causes the validation to fail is a result of having iconPath property in the package-solution.json file. I removed this prop and prepared a new package, but it solved the issue only partially - instead of getting error about AppIconPath, I got one about ShortDescription child element :)

For now I am not sure if it is not caused by MS issue - I opened a ticked on github and asked spfx team for help: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/7987

Comment: Remove the AppIconPath and also remove the "metadata" from the package-solution.json. Add all the descriptions while publishing the app. This way I was able to publish the app.

Comment: It was an issue on the MS side - after few weeks they have solved the issue and for the last few days we are able to update the app package in the App Source again (with AppIconPath and both short and long description properties)